# ClassCastException with StringBuilder and CharSequence

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, charsequence

Why the following code will yield a nice ClassCastException:

```
public static void main(String []args){
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("quaqua");
        StringBuilder s12= (StringBuilder)s1.subSequence(0,3);
        System.out.println(s12);
     }
```

whereas the following code ( substituting StringBuilder with String):

```
public static void main(String []args){
        String s1 = new String("quaqua");
        String s12= (String)s1.subSequence(0,3);
        System.out.println(s12);
     }
```

works fine?;

I understand that there is the method `substring(int begin, int end);` however I am just curious why the cast with StringBuilder (which implements CharSequence) does not work whereas with String works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the actual class that StringBuilder.subSequence returns is String:

```
...
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    return substring(start, end);
}

public String substring(int start, int end) {
    ...
    return new String(value, start, end - start);
}
```

You cannot cast String to StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

In API docs of [`StringBuilder.subSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29):

> An invocation of this method of the form
>
> ```
> sb.subSequence(begin, end)
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
> sb.substring(begin, end)
> ```

Though `String` is a `CharSequence`, `String` is not a `StringBuilder`. So the cast failed.

You can do this instead:

```
StringBuilder s12= new StringBuilder(s1);
s12.setLength(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `subSequence()` methods returns a `String` object at runtime and not a `StringBuilder` object. As per the documentation of [StringBuilder#subSequence()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#subSequence%28int,int%29)

> Returns a new character sequence that is a subsequence of this sequence.
>   An invocation of this method of the form
>
> sb.subSequence(begin, end)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> sb.substring(begin, end)

If you go through the code here :

```
public CharSequence subSequence(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    return this.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
}
```

And if you see the code for `substring()` :

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

It returns a `String` , since `String` implements `CharSequence` interface the return type of `subSequence()` can be that of `CharSequence` , but the internally it works with `String`. And you **cannot** cast `String` to `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Method `String.subSequence` must have returned object of runtime type `String` which simply implements `CharSequence` type.

*Declared return type of method must be **super type** of actual runtime type of returned object.* You are lucky to cast to a correct type.